# Drop down menu selected value

Tags: php, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a form that has drop down menu for menu type. The lists are drinks, appetizer, main and dessert. Every time I want to update menu, the selected type of certain menu is always changed to dessert. It is taken from another table called "menutype" by the way.

```
<select name="new_menutypeid">
    <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM menutype";
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);
        if ($result==false) { die( mysqli_error($mysqli));}
        while ($menutype = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?><option value="<?php echo $menutype['MenuTypeName']; ?>" selected><?php echo $menutype['MenuTypeName']; ?></option><?php}?>
</select>
```

I tried using `<option selected>` but it didn't work (the selected value is dessert)

Comment: Check your HTML code for dropdown which generate all option with `selected` attribute so last option will always selected. You have to put some condition for selected option.

Comment: If i see it like this, it looks like every item has the selected attribute. How does the parsed HTML looks like?

Comment: which value you want to be selected ? and also inspect the dropdown and show your html code of dropdown.